# Spark Managed and Unmanaged Tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

On the new version of the Spark, Spark has its own metastore similar to Hive.
If I create a Spark managed table using Spark.Sql ("create table table_name...."), is it possible to run SQL queries from a SQL client (e.g. SQL workbench) similar to accessing Hive tables?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if your cluster is up and running.